# User getDetailHandler API in AWS was not working in some of the android devices

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am working on AWSCognito login for Android. In that, User getDetailHandler API was not working in some of the android devices(Noted in Karbonn Sparkle and Moto g devices). Seems it works fine in Samsung J7 Please let us know what is the problem actually and it would be helpful for us.

Issue:
That API throws an error in onFailure(Exception e). The error message is "User is not authenticated". In some devices but it was logged in successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provided more context? What is the app trying to do? When does this happen, how do you reproduce this error?
There is not reason for this to fail in some android devices when it's working on others.